# How to consume data in HDFS using Hive with the Kafka-Python client?

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, hdfs, kafka-python

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am new to all of this pipeline stuff :)

I used the kafka-python client to create a producer that sends a csv (one csv row = one kafka message). Note that I serialized it to a string via JSON, and encoded that to bytes as UTF-8. Then I created a consumer which decodes the messages (one csv row is now a string) and prints them to the terminal.
Now I need to save this data in hdfs using hive. I want to insert every message into a hive table and then I want to do a huge select to fetch all the data in one file.

What is the best way to do this using python?

Here is what I have done:

First, I start the zookeeper server:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Then I start the kafka server:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Then I start my consumer and producer:

My Producer:

```
from kafka import KafkaClient, KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer
import csv
import json

client = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

with open("train.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        producer.send('the_topic', json.dumps(row).encode('utf-8'))
```

My Consumer:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

consumer = KafkaConsumer('the_topic')

for msg in consumer:
    decoded_msg = msg.value.decode("utf-8")
    print(decoded_msg)
```

Comment: Technology aside, can you explain what you're trying to do? From the sounds of it, you want to ingest data from CSV files, collate it all, and then write it all to a large flat file?